# How to create and display histogram in OpenCV4Android?

Tags: android, opencv, histogram

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong or give me example how to create AND DISPLAY histogram from grayscale mat in OpenCV4 Android? There is my code...

```
Vector<Mat> bgr_planes = new Vector<Mat>();                                                                                                                                                                                 
Core.split(cleanFaceMatGRAY, bgr_planes);
MatOfInt histSize = new MatOfInt(256);
final MatOfFloat histRange = new MatOfFloat(0f, 256f);
boolean accumulate = false;
Mat b_hist = new  Mat();
Imgproc.calcHist(bgr_planes, new MatOfInt(0),new Mat(), b_hist, histSize, histRange, accumulate);
```

And then I try to set it to Image view to see it:

```
    ivPickedPhoto.setImageBitmap(AppTools.createBitmapFromMat(b_hist, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888));
```

Method for display was created on my own:

public class AppTools {

```
public static Bitmap createBitmapFromMat(Mat mat, Bitmap.Config config) {
    Bitmap bmp2 = null;

    bmp2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(mat.cols(), mat.rows(), config);
    Utils.matToBitmap(mat, bmp2);   
    return bmp2;
}
```

This gives me an error in the ivPickedPhoto(...) lane:

```
12-10 21:12:59.910: E/AndroidRuntime(10301): Caused by: CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp:98: error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 || src.type() == CV_8UC3 || src.type() == CV_8UC4 in function void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean)
```

I guess my problem is with the way I want to display the histogram... prolly I cant convert it to bmp. What is a good way to show histogram?

Comment: Hey how did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The [OpenCV Java Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/android/Utils.html#matToBitmap%28org.opencv.core.Mat,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29) states that the `Mat` object you are passing should be of type `CV_8UC1, CV_8UC3 or CV_8UC4`. The documentation of [calcHist](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#calcHist%28java.util.List,%20org.opencv.core.MatOfInt,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.MatOfInt,%20org.opencv.core.MatOfFloat,%20boolean%29) doesn't really specify which type you should expect your `b_Hist` to be, but since it is complaining about the `Mat` type:

```
error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 || src.type() == CV_8UC3 || src.type() == CV_8UC4
```

you should probably convert it to either of the three above formats.